# "Responsible for official written communication" in resume?

Tags: resume, communication, language

I'm debating whether or not to include in my resume that I frequently prepare and send out official public communication in my organization, to show both language and responsibility skills.

1. Is this a worthwhile addition?
2. If so, what would be a good way to put it? I'm thinking about "Responsible for official written communication", but that can probably be improved.

Comment: Probably matters what kind of job you're applying for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding "*Responsible for official written communication*" is too vague to be worthwhile in a resume. "*official written communication*" could be anything from legal documents to emails with customers. You need to be more specific about what exactly you were responsible for. Here are some examples of things that might be worth including in your resume:

> - Responsible for creating official company press release statements [include link to example]
> - Managed company's official social media account [include link]
> - Provided regular project reports to customers
> - Prepared legal contracts for company merger

Or whatever it is you actually did. Be specific, and be relevant to the job you are applying for. If you want to work in PR, then the fact that you ran the company's social media accounts is important. If you want to be on the company's legal team, then it may be less important. That's up for you to judge.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the well thought-out answer!

Comment: @Zubo While I appreciate the accept, I always recommend waiting at least a day before accepting an answer. Your question has only been up an hour, and there are lots of regular users who haven't even seen it yet. Though you might like this answer, you never know if another user will come along and post something even better!

Comment: Good point. Will do.